# Showing base64 pdf file in iframe tag

Tags: javascript, base64

Unable to display the file with more than 1 mb in embed a pdf file.

How can we solve this issue

It is working below file size less than 1 mb

```html
<iframe id="iframepdf" src="files/example.pdf"></iframe>
```

Does anyone have any ideas on why this is happening, how I can fix it

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear whether the issue is from browser limitations or network capability.

In my opinion, I recommend checking out these potential solutions:

1. Review your browser console logs for any error messages that might appear during file rendering processes.
2. Trying other web browsers, since different ones have unique external plugin-based systems for displaying PDFs.
3. Testing with different large-sized files.

In case it still does not work, maybe consider using third-party PDF libraries such as [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/?from_rs=true) or [Viewer.js](https://viewerjs.org/) to resolve browser limitations.

Good luck with solving the problem!